# Magento 2: Show new label for products that have "set product as new from'

Tags: magento2

I'm using Magento 2.3.5. I have a label attribute for products in which you can add labels like 'popular', 'must have', 'our choice' etc.

There is an attribute called  'Set Product as New From' and I want it to show a 'new' label on the productpage if 'Set Product as New From' is active. How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

$fromDate = $_product->getNewsFromDate();

$toDate = $_product->getNewsToDate();